# trying to click a div and use the url stored in another div to go a to a landing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am capturing data from json in the following format. (I'm using getjson and $.each to return the data, however I am skipping that part in this question)

```
event += '<div class="eventHolder">'; 
event += '<div class="eLink">'+entry.href+'</div>';
event += '<div class="eventName">'+ entry.title + '</div>';
event += '</div>';
```

Storing the output in a div

```
$('#output').html(event);
```

Now trying to create a scenario where I will click the 'eventName' and it will go to a landing page of 'eLink'

I am storing the url in `eLink`, how should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can try to replace your div by a link like this (and delete your div witj eLink class if you don't need to display url) :

```
event += '<div class="eventHolder">'; 
event += '<a href="'+entry.href+'">'+ entry.title + '</a>';
event += '</div>';
```

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

When you click on `.eventName` div, you redirect to the link contained in `.eLink` div.

---

### JavaScript/jQuery

```
/* On click of 'eventName' class element */
$('.eventName').click(function () {
    /* Redirect to the page link contained in the 'eLink' class element */
    window.location.href = $('.eLink').text();
});
```

### [Live Demo (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/wEaSQ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
$('.eventName').click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).parent().find('.eLink').text()
});
```